# ios binding UIControlEventTouchUpInside to container does not make views in container to respond event

Tags: ios, events, uitableview, uicontrol

hi i have a container that has 2 subviews, an image and a label, 
i have binded the events to the container to respond to UIControlEventTouchUpInside, the whole idea is so that when user clicks anywhere on the container, including the image and label within it, the event should be triggered.

not sure if this is a problem, but when binding the container, the container already has the image and label view populate in it

problem is i am not seeing the expected behaviour
clicking on label an image does not trigger the event
but clicking on regions outside the label and image but still within the container triggers the event....can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Don't have to bind  UIControlEventTouchUpInside to a Type View .You can use [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead or [UITouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to accomplish what you want.